# Сервер-демон на Perl

Tags: perl

ЗДравствуйте!
проблема такая - надо написать свой сервер-демон
Как понять, что это именно демон? Сервер отказывается отправлять файлы и писать логфайл..
Для него это что запрещено?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

# сервер с постветвлением и двусторонним обменом информацией,  реализованный в виде   демона

use IO::Socket;
use Net::hostent;               
use Sys::Hostname;              
use POSIX;
use KAV_Protocol;

print `clear`;
$server_port = 1027;
$server = IO::Socket::INET->new( LocalPort => $server_port,
                             Proto     => 'tcp',
                             Reuse     => 1,
                             Listen    => SOMAXCONN )
or die "Неполучается создать сокет!\n";

sub REAPER
{
1 until (-1 == waitpid(-1, WNOHANG));
$SIG{CHLD} = \&REAPER;
}
$SIG{CHLD} = \&REAPER;

daemonize();
print "Сервер запущен...\n";
print "Сервер доступен по адресу:\n\t",server_addr(),"\n";
while (my $client = $server->accept())
{
last if $time_to_die;
next if $pid = fork;                #завершаем родительский процесс        
die "fork: $!" unless defined $pid;

close $server;
commands($client);
exit;
} continue
{
close $client;
}

sub daemonize
{
chdir("/tmp")
or die "Can't chdir to /tmp: $!";

# Клонирование и завершение родительского процесса
my $pid = fork;
exit if $pid;
die "Can't fork: $!\n" unless defined($pid);

#Закрываем стандартные дискрипторы файлов, вновь открывая их для /dev/null
for my $handle (*STDIN, *STDOUT, *STDERR) 
{
    open($handle, "+<", "/dev/null")
      || die "can't reopen $handle to /dev/null: $!";
 }

# Разрываем связь с управлющим терминалом, с которого был запущен процесс
POSIX::setsid() or die "Couldn't start a new session: $!\n" ;

#Сбрасываем флаг, означающий, что мы хотим корректно завершиться
$time_to_die = 0;   
#Перехватываем фатальные сигналы
$SIG{INT} = $SIG{TERM} = $SIG{HUP} = \&signal_handler;
$SIG{PIPE} = 'IGNORE';
}
#Устанавливаем флаг, означающий, что мы хотим корректно завершиться
sub signal_handler
{
$time_to_die = 1;
}
```

вот код,стандартный демон..пример из всех учебников

Comment: в линуксе демоном называют любую программу, которая может отцепиться от текущей консоли и работать тихонько (или не сильно) в фоне. Программы с GUI демонами не являются.

А вот почему он у Вас отказывается писать логфайл и отправлять файлы - это уже вопрос к Вам. Значит так его написали.

Comment: добавила код, может посмотрите

Comment: А где там запись лог-файла?

Comment: запись в протоколе идет..

Comment: там все стандартно 
 

    open FILE_LOG, ">file_log.txt";

Comment: Там всё "нестандартно": начиная с отсутствия use strict и заканчивая такой формой open... В любом случае прежде чем что-то демонизировать, я бы посоветовал прогнать скрипт в обычном режиме. Без хэндлов STD* вы просто не можете увидеть ошибок, если они появятся в райнтайме:

    [22:37:25] klopp:dev $ ./1.pl
    Undefined subroutine &main::server_addr called at ./1.pl line 38.

Без этой строчки - вот висит:

    [22:48:20] klopp:~ $ ps ax | grep "1.pl"
    16439 pts/5    S+     0:00 /usr/bin/perl ./1.pl
    16525 pts/8    S+     0:00 grep --colour=auto 1.pl

(что за радость print в /dev/null?)

Comment: нет, все равно не понятно, другие серверы пишу - с постветвлением, без ветвления,распределенный - все работает - а демон с этим протоколом только отвечает на команды получить адрес и текущую дату..

Comment: Вы уже запустили скрипт без daemonize(), с выводом информации в ключевых точках? Работает? Что пишет?

Comment: KAV_Protocol что такое вообще ?

Answer (score 1):

проверяте код возврата из open

Comment: После демонизации ни одного STD* не остаётся, в лог не пишется по определению (open вернул ошибку). Что с этой проверкой делать? В текущей архитектуре сервера - абсолютно не информативна эта проверка будет.

Comment: вы уверены, что ваш демон открывает лог-файл /tmp?

попробуйте не закрывать std* дескрипторы, и запустить программу под отладчиком.

можно проверить, не используется ли у вас selinux, который запрещает вам писать в tmp и использовать сокеты выше 1024